# Android ANR: thread waiting on lock that it already holds?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I'm seeing an ANR in my Android application. The stack of my main thread shows this happens while it is running a DB query. As per the [Keeping your app responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) guidelines, this is probably wrong and should be moved to a worker thread.

However, I want to check that this operation is just slow and not deadlocked. What I'm confused by, is the stack shows this thread `tid=1` is waiting for `<0x41788f70>`, which is held by ... `tid=1`! **How is this possible?** Surely if it is this thread holding the object, there's no need to wait? What am I missing here?

I can't find any other reference to the handle `<0x41788f70>` anywhere else in the stack dump.

Thanks for your help.

Here's the stack of the main thread:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41788ea0 self=0x41677588
  | sysTid=19868 nice=-11 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074336084
  | state=S schedstat=( 530094727 210277810 1460 ) utm=36 stm=17 core=1
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x41788f70> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=1 (main)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:735)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:397)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:905)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:586)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
...
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing the code. What operations are you performing on the worker thread?

Comment: @Alex - sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. There is no worker thread involved here as far as I can see. (While there are other threads in the thread dump, none of them have any reference to the handle `0x41788f70` mentioned in the main stack.) What I'm wondering is how thread tid=1 can have a line in the stack saying "waiting on ... , held by tid=1".

Comment: What method call caused the deadlock? I'm not sure if the easiest way to analyze the problem is by looking at low-level reference addresses and thread IDs in the logcat.

Comment: I'm not certain that there was a deadlock. It could just be that the DB query was slow (I think you get the ANR if the main thread is unresponsive for 5 seconds). Also, this is from a user report, so I don't know any more details at the moment (just a report saying they saw the ANR popup).
If I was sure it was just a slow query I'd move it off the main thread and that would be fine. But I want to be certain that it isn't blocked; seeing the TIMED_WAIT on an object makes me suspect that it might be, but I still don't understand why it would be blocked if it is this thread that holds the lock.

Comment: Are you performing any queries in your application that might take a long time? Because if so, the easiest solution is to the probable solution is to just move it on a background thread. `SqliteDatabase` is thread safe and well-tested, so if there is a deadlock it likely isn't coming from the framework code... and if you aren't using any other worker threads in your application currently then I'm guessing what happened is the main thread was killed by the system due to an ANR. As for the logcat... it would be nice if there was more information (i.e. which screen the user was on, etc.).